# How to add a custom field to Magento catalog_product_option_type_value table

Tags: database, custom-options, eav

I'm just wondering if there is an easier way?

What I was going to do is create my own custom table with a reference to the option_type_id from the catalog_product_option_type_value because I don't like altering the tables directly and then when the user saves their product option, save my field value with it.  I see a lot of EAV tables but I don't think I can use these with options.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you want to add a custom field, there is no easier way :) Give us a global picture!

Comment: No, that's it. My global picture was not doing something that will take along time if there is an easier way I wasn't aware of. Still new to Magento and I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: If you want to put your response as an answer, I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to achieve? If you want to add a custom field, there is no easier way :) Give us a global picture!